# AOW Pension and UK State Pension Rights

Tags: united-kingdom, netherlands, pension

I will reach state pension age in 2016 and have 35 qualifying years in the UK, so will receive a full pension. Between 1992 and 2005 I lived and worked in Holland, so have 13 years of contributions towards an AOW Pension as well. Will I receive the AOW as well as my State Pension for those years? These combined years give me a work history of 45 years in total.

Comment: Welcome to Expatriates! I edited your question slightly to try to clarify what you were asking. Please read it over and make sure I didn't change what you meant. Feel free to revert my changes, or make any edits you think will improve your question, with the [edit] link below your question post.

Comment: See also http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/985/what-would-happen-with-my-pension-if-i-leave-europe-and-never-return?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You should indeed be entitles to the dutch AOW pension. The sum will be 13/50 = 26% of the full pension.

Depending on your marital state, this adds up to a pre-tax amount between 200 (married) and 300 (single) in Euro per month. There is a possibility that your spouse was also under the dutch social security system during those 13 years, in which case 2 times 200 euros.

Pension age is currently 65.25 years and is being gradually raised. The start date of pension entitlement hence depends on your exact age.